# Using pandas how do I split a dataframe into multiple dataframes of size N by rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file full of a few thousand rows. I load a file in and convert it to a pandas dataframe but I then wish to split the file every 12 rows and store it as a list of dataframes. How do I do this?

```
EVALUATION_FILE = 'training/evaluation.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(
    EVALUATION_FILE,
    engine='python',
    index_col=None
)
```

I load my file in like so but I wish to change it so every 12 rows it splits and appends to a list. How would I do this?

Comment: `df_lst = [df.loc[i:i+12] for i in range(0,len(df), 12)]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [`chunksize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

When this argument is used, `read_csv` returns an iterator in which each iteration returns a new chunk.

```
data = [*pd.read_csv(EVALUATION_FILE, chunksize=12)]
```

---

#### [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

If by chance you have already read in your dataframe and you want to split it after the fact.  Use `nupmy.split` with an array that defines your split points.

```
data = np.split(df, range(12, len(df), 12))
```

Comment: @Erfan it is variable unpacking and in a square bracket context it creates a list from the iterator.  EG `list('ABCD')` is the same as `[*'ABCD']`

Answer (score 2):

Check `groupby` after `read_csv`

```
data=[y for x , y in df.groupby(data.index//12)]
```

---

```
EVALUATION_FILE = 'training/evaluation.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(
    EVALUATION_FILE,
    engine='python',
    index_col=None
)
```